# How to setup Unity desktop switcher as a 2D Torus network?

Tags: unity, virtualdesktop

Currently I have my desktops set up like this as a 3x3 grid:
[3x3 Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i3Va.png)

I would like it to work like a 2D torus network, i.e. if I am using the top left desktop and press ctrl+alt+left I swap to the top right desktop. Any ideas about how to do this?

Thanks for any ideas.